# cas not redirect to login-page

Tags: java, spring-security, cas

i have a problem just as title, and the http-status is "302 Moved Temporarily". my security-app.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Load parameters from context.xml -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>
    <sec:http entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint" auto-config="true">   
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />      
        <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/loggedOut.html"/>
        <sec:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casFilter" />
    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
        <property name="service" value="http://localhost:8080/test/j_spring_cas_security_check" />
        <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="casFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="casEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginUrl" value="https://localhost:7443/cas/login" />
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="casAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService" ref="myUserService" />
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
        <property name="ticketValidator">
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="https://localhost:7443/cas" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="key" value="an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myUserService" class="com.security.myUserDetailService">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDatasource"/>
    </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup  id="optaDatasource" jndi-name="jdbc/mydb"/>
</beans>
```

and the web.xml ( cas listener & some filters ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
...
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mytest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Listener für Spring -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Listener for CAS -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
...
    <!-- CAS Single Sign Out -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <!-- UTF-8 Encoding Filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CEF</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CEF</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>mytest</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
... 
</web-app>
```

server.xml in Tomcat (define connector to https://cas):

```
    ...
<Connector port="7443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="caslocalhost" keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\caskslocalhost.jks" keystorePass="changeit"/>
```

Am I missing something?
I would really appreciate any tip

ps:
Info of response header:

```
Content-Length  0
Date    Tue, 20 Mar 2012 14:12:23 GMT
Location    https://localhost:7443/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftest%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=A69FD95FB79B21810B2988A02CCFD78C; Path=/test
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really explain what the problem. 302 is what you would expect for a redirect (what is the location header?). I think you'll need to give more context and explain your observations. Also, check the debug log from Spring Security as it should give a pretty detailed commentary of how requests are handled. I would also remove `auto-config` from your setup if you are using CAS.

Comment: i had add info of response header. If i give http://localhost:8080/test/... , it should be redirected to https://localhost:7443/cas/login. But nothing happend, although it is already in "Location".

Comment: Is it related to Ajax Request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the settings are correct. 
and the reason is found : ajax request.
I must modify the code of js-site.